# Find x-values of several peaks of a data set

Tags: find, max, argmax

in the following figure two data sets are plotted.

The values of each data set are in the following form:

```
PixelNo
0       821.0
1       943.0
2       806.0
3       753.0
4       834.0
        ...  
3586    932.0
3587    828.0
3588    786.0
3589    767.0
3590    832.0
Name: Calib_1, Length: 3591, dtype: float64
```

How do you find x-values of those peaks that exceed an arbitrary value, say 0.35?
[image: Plot]
Regards,

Karl